# Error detected from emxArray_uint8_T: .text+0xc1): undefined reference to `emxInit_uint8_T1(emxArray_uint8_T**, int)'?

Tags: c++, matlab-coder

I write a matlab function that calculates entropy of gray scale image: "score=score_entropy(image)" then use matlab coder to convert it to c++

c++ code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "score_entropy.cpp"
#include"score_entropy_emxAPI.cpp"

class image
{
public: 
unsigned char *im;
int h1,w1;
voide scoreimage();
}
void image::scoreimage( )
{ emxArray_uint8_T* I=emxCreateWrapper_uint8_T(im,h1,w1);
double ent=score_entropy(I);
 emxDestroyArray_uint8_T(I);
}
void mexFunction( int nl, mxArray *pl[], int nr, const mxArray *pr[] )
{
image.im = ( unsigned char*) mxGetData(pr[0]);
image. h1 = (int) imgSize[0];
 image. w1 = (int) imgSize[1];
image.scoreimage();
}
```

The definition of score_entropy.cpp :
double score_entropy( const emxArray_uint8_T *im)

I found a list of errors :

`` (.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `emxInit_uint8_T1(emxArray_uint8_T**, int)'
(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `emxEnsureCapacity_uint8_T(emxArray_uint8_T*, int)'
(.text+0x16c):undefined reference to `emxInit_uint8_T(emxArray_uint8_T**, int)'
..
..
(.rdata$.refptr.rtMinusInf[.refptr.rtMinusInf]+0x0):
undefined reference to `rtMinusInf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

can any one help to correct this code?

Answer (score 0):

Compile and link all of the generated CPP files together and that will fix the linker issue. It looks like you're just linking a few of them.

Also make sure you call the generated `_initialize` function before you call your generated entry point.

Comment: I call score_entropy_initialize() before call entry point but still have same errors plus (.text+0x107c):
undefined reference to `score_entropy_initialize()'. what can I do else and how link all files.